# How to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (z-w)^{(n/2 - 1)}w^{(n/2 - 1)}\ dw$?

Tags: integration, convolution

I am trying to integrate: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (z-w)^{(n/2 - 1)}(w)^{(n/2 - 1)}\ dw$$
where $n$ is an integer and $z$ is real.
I tried repeated integration by parts but wasn't able to reduce this. If anyone could provide a hint I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: The integral does not exist, either as an improper integral or as a Lebesgue integral, for any *real* $n \geq 1$. As an extreme, $n=2$ leads to an integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1\,\mathrm{d}w,$$ which is of course $+\infty$ in either senses mentioned above. Are you trying to interpret your integral as something else (such as a principal value or a distributional integral)?

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for your response. Sorry, I realized I made a mistake in this exercise and the integral should've been something else.